# MySQL SELECT All Grouped With LEFT JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

**Current Result**:

```
SELECT CT.cat2 as Cat, SUM(MT.`revenue`) as Revenue
                FROM sales MT
                    LEFT JOIN `2016productcodes` CT 
                        ON MT.productsku = CT.productcode 
                WHERE MT.`date` BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-13' AND revenue > 0
                GROUP BY CT.cat2

Cat        | Revenue   |
---------------------------
cat1       | 250.00    |
cat3       | 100.00    |
cat5       | 32.00     |
```

I want to show ALL Grouped Categories though (to display NULL, BLANK or "0.00" when there is no Revenue.. doesn't matter).

**Desired Result**:

```
Cat        | Revenue   |
---------------------------
cat1       | 250.00    |
cat2       |           |
cat3       | 100.00    | 
cat4       |           |
cat5       | 32.00     |
```

I have tried this Query, and it indeed shows all Categories but it groups all Revenue in each Category (Revenue is always the same).

```
SELECT cat2 as Cat, (SELECT
        SUM(MT.`revenue`)
                FROM 2016productcodes CT 
                    LEFT JOIN `sales` MT
                        ON MT.productsku = CT.productcode

                WHERE MT.`date` BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-13'

           ) Revenue
FROM 2016productcodes
GROUP BY cat2
```

Comment: Have you tried simply reversing the JOIN order? (i.e. `\`2016productcodes\` CT LEFT JOIN sales MT ...`) .... and you'll want to move the current WHERE criteria into the join criteria.

Comment: No luck when I reverse JOIN, typical same results.

Comment: If you don't move the `WHERE` critieria into the `JOIN` criteria, the query will act as an `INNER JOIN` (as the results for "cats" without sales will have `MT` values that are NULL which the WHERE will filter out.)

Comment: Bingo indeed it worked.  Had to index a few fields, but it works great now, thanks!